# Sync files from NAS to local harddrive?

Tags: ubuntu, network-attached-storage, hard-drive, copy, synchronization

i need a way in ubuntu to sync like 1tb of files from a NAS to a local harddrive, connected by ethernet (directly). any suggestions? it should include a progress bar, that's why 'cp' isn't the right thing!

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use rsync it does provide progress information with the --progress switch although it is not a progress bar.

Comment: well, progress information is fine. it's just important that i see that something is happening.

Answer (score 0):

cp -v certainly gives you a clue that something is happening. Fro a whole disk or folder tree : cp -dpRv